# How to make my scrollbar pass above my content

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I would like to make my scrollbar pass on my table and not let a space between the window.
My overflow-y: scroll is on a div.

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/21/5/1558714720-capture.png

My scrollbar css :

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#board::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(186, 186, 192, 0.4);

  opacity: 0.4;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: rgba(160, 160, 165, 0.85);
}
```

Do there is a way to do it pls? Seems like it's not really possible with only css but i don't want to use a plugin

Thanks

Comment: This is likely due to the container itself, not the scroller.

Comment: It's what i seen. Only work on body ? There is no way to work on my div ?